# FastAPI throws an error (Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "api")

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I tried to run FastAPI using uvicorn webserver but it throws an error.

I run this command,

```
uvicorn api:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
```

but there is an error in the terminal.

```
Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Started reloader process [23445]
Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "api".
Stopping reloader process [23445]
```

Comment: what is the path of the python file which declares the `app` variable ?

Comment: in my case, my filename was `uvicorn.py` and `uvicorn uvicorn:app` throws error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Error loading ASGI app. Import string "main" must be in format "<module>:<attribute>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71036753/error-error-loading-asgi-app-import-string-main-must-be-in-format-module)

Answer (score 277, accepted):

## TL;DR

Add the directory name in front of your filename

```py
uvicorn src.main:app
```

or `cd` into that directory

```py
cd src
uvicorn main:app
```

## Long Answer

It happens because you are not in the same folder with your FastAPI app instance more specifically:

Let's say i have an app-tree like this;

```
my_fastapi_app/
├── app.yaml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── src
│   └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── test_xx.py
    └── test_yy.py

$ pwd         # Present Working Directory
/home/yagiz/Desktop/my_fastapi_app
```

I'm not inside the same folder with my app instance, so if I try to run my app with uvicorn I'll get an error like yours

```
$ uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [40645] using statreload
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".
```

The answer is so simple, add the folder name in front of your filename

```
uvicorn src.main:app --reload
```

or you can change your working directory

```
cd src
```

Now i'm inside of the folder with my app instance

```
src
└── main.py
```

Run your uvicorn again

```
$ uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [40726] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [40728]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Comment: Well, I'm at the same folder as my main.py file but it doesn't want to run

Comment: Hi @Carlos3dx what is FastAPI instance's name is it called app?  for example if you declare like `other_app = FastAPI()` you need to run as `main:other_app` , if it doesn't works either, i can help you from FastAPI's [gitter](https://gitter.im/tiangolo/fastapi)

Comment: There was another file in the application importing main, the error message was related to that import, not the main I passed to uvicorn, but cause there was no stacktrace it looked like uvicorn cannot foun main module. Rearranged the code and now works perfect

Comment: another option, uvicorn has a path parameter:
--app-dir src. 

running uvicorn --help,  shows all options

Comment: I encountered this issue because I mistakenly added `.py` in the command like this `uvicorn main.py:app`. It should be `uvicorn main:app`.

Comment: Just FYI, I was running this from main, and could not get it to work until I added an `__init__.py` to the package directory, even with `pkg.module:app`. Python 3.10.4

Comment: What if I'm using docker and directory name is `/app` (not `app`)

Comment: Beware that this error also appears if you haven't saved the main.py file yet...

Answer (score 16):

One reason this might be happening is that you are using:

```
uvicorn src/main:app --reload
```

instead of the **correct syntax**:

```
uvicorn src.main:app --reload
```

Notice the **.** instead of the **/**
Currently auto-completion in the terminal suggests the wrong format.

---

That's assuming that:

(1) your structure is something like this:

```
project_folder/
├── some_folder
├── src
│   └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── test_xx.py
    └── test_yy.py
```

(2) your `FastAPI()` object is indeed assigned to an object named `app` in `main.py`:

```
app = FastAPI()
```

(3) you are running the uvicorn command from the `project_folder`, e.g.:

```
(venv) <username>@<pcname>:~/PycharmProjects/project_folder$ uvicorn src.main:app --reload
```

Answer (score 10):

**I had the same problem and solved it adding package name before main, in your case trying:**

```
uvicorn src.main:app --reload
```

**may solve the problem**

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me [look at the docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#:%7E:text=the%20command%20uvicorn%20main%3Aapp%20refers%20to%3A) for fastAPI. I am very thankful I ran accross that as the Python script needs to be named `main.py` not `app.py`

The command `uvicorn main:app` refers to:

1. `main`: the file `main.py` (the Python "module").
2. `app`: the object created inside of `main.py` with the line `app = FastAPI()`
3. `--reload`: make the server restart after code changes. Only use for
   development.

Comment: you can name it as you want as long as you reference it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason for this error: there is a circular reference between files.

Example:

- `main.py`:

  ```py
  from tools import validator

  # ...

  class GlobalException(Exception):
      # ...
  ```
- `/tools/validator.py`:

  ```py
  from main import GlobalException
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same issue,
being a total beginner to FastAPI, the solution given by Yagiz Degirmenci
helped to come up with a simple idea for beginners like me, i.e

```
cd directory of code
uvicorn fast-api:main --reload
```

PS. fast-api is the name of my file (i.e fast-api.py)

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is important that you name your file main.py otherwise it won't work.

Edit: Actually I was running Jupyter Notebook on port 8888 so that port was already occupied. If you have to run Jupyter notebook, run it after running the API server, the notebook will automatically run on 8889.
Alternatively, you can run the API server on a different port.

Answer (score 2):

- **Step-1** make sure your main file is located in the same directory of your terminal/command prompt, use `ls` command

```
(virtual-env) shayon@shayon-X556UQK:~/Documents/python-fast-api$ ls
main.py  __pycache__  README.md  requirements.txt  virtual-env
```

- **Step-2** check the directory of your terminal using `pwd` command

```
(virtual-env) shayon@shayon-X556UQK:~/Documents/python-fast-api$ pwd
/home/shayon/Documents/python-fast-api
```

- **Step-3** check the name of your object - here `app` is the object of FastAPI so we need to use the command `uvicorn main:app --reload`, if you keep the object name `app1` you need to run `uvicorn main:app1 --reload`

```
(virtual-env) shayon@shayon-X556UQK:~/Documents/python-fast-api$ cat main.py
```

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

- **Step-4** In my case, I made a mistake making command of `uvicorn main.py:app --reload` and this was the reason for my error. The command should be `uvicorn main:app --reload` (without dot py extension)

Answer (score 1):

Hit the Save button in VS Code etc because sometimes it will throw this error if you have not saved the file. Happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using the following in my main:

```
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"index": "root"}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    uvicorn.run(f"{Path(__file__).stem}:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8888, reload=True)
```

and then from the terminal, I typed `uvicorn main:app --reload`  as my main.py is in my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use this folder structure and configuration where main is in parent directory
[image]

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: FastAPI",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "uvicorn",
            "args": [
                "main:app"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI(
    title="test",
    description="test",
    version="0.0.1",
)
if __name__ == "__main__":
import uvicorn

uvicorn.run(
    "main:app",
    host="0.0.0.0",
    reload=True,
    port=3001,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also another reason for this error:

There's already a file named exactly like your running folder, then it will make a conflict to the system.

Example you have a file inside a folder named `test_app/main.py`, then you should run `uvicorn test_app.main:app --reload` to run the app.

But, if you have a file named `test_app.py` (which is the same name as the folder above), it will throw the error when you run the app.

[image]

So the solution is to rename the folder or rename the file so they won't be conflict to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm , the reason could be the source directory not being set correctly. For example, I was trying to configure Python remote debugger using docker-compose and my folder structure was like this:

```
my_app_name
├── docker-compose.yml
├── src
│   └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── test_file1.py
    └── test_file2.py
```

I had the src folder inside the root folder, which contained the main.py file. In PyCharm project settings, by default your source folder is set to root.But if you have a nested structure like the case above, you have to go to **Preferences->Project->Project Structure->Sources** and add your src folder under Source Folders.

Answer (score 0):

don't give the same name for your python file like uvicorn.py,Folder same name, package name