# FastAPI says missing folder name as module

Tags: python, pymongo, fastapi

I have a question related to FastAPI with uvicorn in pycharm. My project is having following structure:

```
LearningPy <folder name> 
 |  
 |-- apis <folder name>  
 -----|--modelservice <folder name>  
 ---------|--dataprovider.py  
 ---------|--main.py  
 ---------|--persondetails.py  
 -----|--config.py
```

First I was using following path : **D:\Learnings\apis** and ran following code :  uvicorn main:app --reload
then it was giving error :

```
Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Started reloader process [23445]
Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "apis".
```

However, after reading suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819376/fastapi-throws-an-error-error-loading-asgi-app-could-not-import-module-api), I have changed the path to **D:\Learnings\apis\modeservice** and above error gone but now it started throwing a different error :
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apis'**

Here are my main.py and config.py code files :

main.py --

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from datetime import datetime

from apis import config
from apis.modelservice import dataprovider

app = FastAPI(debug=True)
def get_application() -> FastAPI:
    application = FastAPI(title="PersonProfile", description="Learning Python CRUD",version="0.1.0")
    origins = [
        config.API_CONFIG["origin_local_ip"],
        config.API_CONFIG["origin_local_url"]
    ]
    application.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )
    #application.include_router(processA.router)
    return application

app = get_application()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"main": "API Server " + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")}

@app.get("/dbcheck")
def read_root():
    try:
        dataprovider.get_db().get_collection("Person")
    except Exception as e:
        return {"failed":e}
    else:
        return { "connected":True}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

And here is config.py--

```
API_CONFIG = {
    "origin_local_ip": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "origin_local_url": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

This project is being built on React+Mongo+python (pymongo for connecting mongodb).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the same directory with `main.py`?  check this answer [fastapi asgi app couldnt not import module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819376/fastapi-throws-an-error-error-loading-asgi-app-could-not-import-module-api/62934660#62934660)

Comment: No, the config.py file is outside of main.py folder. and Thanks Yagizcan, I was exactly read your answer. but the error is now coming due to calling module outside outside of modeservice folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try changing directory to `modelservice` and run the `uvicorn main:app --reload` again, if you get an error add in to the question

Comment: Ya, I did that Yagizcan, as you see I have already added that part in question (find this : I have changed the path to D:\Learnings\apis\modeservice ) and then the error is coming relateds to apis fodler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your application is your module organization,firstly i tried your folder structring i get the same errors as yours, i debugged it a little bit, i found the error was on importing config so i dived more deeply to understand why Python can not import your config,

I created a script on the top folder to find out why. Also added in print line in the `config.py` and `modelservice.main.py`

```
print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<20} | __package__={2<20}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
import apis.config
import apis.modelservice.main
```

This was the structure

```
apis
├── config.py
└── modelservice
    └── main.py
```

I run the script in the top folder script named main.py, It ended up with this result:

```
 __file__=main.py | __name__=__main__ | __package__=None                
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/test/apis/config.py | __name__=apis.config | package__=apis                
apis.config
__file__=/home/yagiz/Desktop/test/apis/modelservice/main.py | __name__=apis.modelservice.main | __package__=apis.modelservice
```

It felt strange because i should be able to relative import, but when i tried to import that what

```
from .. import config
```

it returned:

```
  File "./main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .. import config
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Just for the testing it out i tried this structure, also i used **absolute import** `import config:`

```
apis/
├── modelservice
    ├── config.py
    ├── main.py

INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [14155] using statreload
__file__=./main.py  | __name__=main | __package__=                    
__file__=./config.py  | __name__=config   | __package__= config
INFO:     Started server process [14157]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Everything worked fine like that, so the problem is with your module organization and how you importing things so take a look at them again.

Comment: Now I just cut and pasted config file inside modelservice folder and also changed the import namespaces of main.py like this ````from modelservice import config```` but then it says ````No module named modelservice```` .

Comment: you just need   `import config`

Answer (score 2):

Added to what Yagizcan answered above, if anyone still getting module import error in pycharm then change the sources root to the code folder from File menu.

```
LearningPy <folder name> 
 |  
 |-- apis <folder name>  
 -----|--modelservice <folder name>  
 ---------|--dataprovider.py  
 ---------|--persondetails.py  
------|--main.py    
------|--config.py
```

Here I have moved the main.py outside of modelservice folder. since main.py will be running as api. Then, to run the code I have added following code
`uvicorn path to apisfolder.main:app --reload`. And now it ran without any problem.