# ERROR: Error loading ASGI app. Import string "main" must be in format "<module>:<attribute>"

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn, asgi

Trying to test my first FastAPI application using uvicorn.

The following code was written on Jupyter Notebook and saved as `'main.py'` in the directory: `/home/user`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

From the same directory I am running:

```
$uvicorn main --reload
```

It throws the following error:

> ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Import string "main" must be in
> format ":".

Answer (score 5):

As the error indicates, the "string `main` must be in format `"<module>:<attribute>"`". Hence, you should use:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

I would highly suggest you take a look at the [FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/).

> The command uvicorn `main:app` refers to:
>
> - `main`: the file `main.py` (the Python `"module"`).
> - `app`: the object created inside of `main.py` with the line `app = FastAPI()`.
> - `--reload`: make the server restart after code changes. **Only use    for development**.

Answer (score 1):

##### The exact same error message, however a different scenario

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def index():
    return {'Message': 'This is only a message!'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', port=8000, reload=True)
```

This message might occur because of a call on the method run, where it does not accept positional nor keyword arguments as variables. But rather as plain text. Like done in the example above.