fastapi and uvicorn problems
I have downloaded fastapi, but got an error of no module found.
So I installed in virtual environment, where I used
pip install fastapi[all]

main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

I am expecting: {message: Hello World}
When I am trying to run this I get
(venv) C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\API>uvicorn main:app
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Attribute "app" not found in module "main".

I even tried
uvicorn main:app --reload 

but it still did not work.  Where am I going wrong? I am sure that I am using virtual environment, and virtual environment python interpreter, too.

What happens if you add raise RuntimeError(__file__) in main.py in a new line above from fastapi import FastAPI and run uvicorn main:app again?

See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819376/fastapi-throws-an-error-error-loading-asgi-app-could-not-import-module-api
